# Double.ToString for formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net, string-formatting

I need to format a number with a specific format. I don't want to decide on the format with the regional settings of the computer so I'm trying:

```
string s = "219171"
string result = Convert.ToDouble(s).ToString("0,0.0") //219,171.0
string result = Convert.ToDouble(s).ToString("0.0,0") //219171.00
```

I want to display it as

> 219.171,00

Thank you

Comment: You need to use a formatting culture that tells the formatter what the thousands separator and the decimal point are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a custom NumberFormatInfo instance and pass that in when calling ToString().

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";

double s = 219171;
string result = s.ToString("N2", nfi);
```

`NumberFormatInfo` belongs to `System.Globalization`

Comment: this solved the problem. thank you, first time a "Murphy" does any good to my life :)

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the locale for which you want the number formatted in the `Double.ToString(IFormatProvider provider)` overload. It you don't supply it, `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUILocale` will be used. If you want it to be independant of the computer settings, you can use `Double.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

If you want to completely customize the formatting (e. g. exactly x digit before/after the decimal seperator), look it up in a [formatstring overview](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/).

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
string result = (Convert.ToDouble(s) / 1000).ToString("##0.000\\,00");
```

Dividing 1000 changes the location of the decimal point. Each # or 0 is a digit.

Alternatively, you could use:

```
string result = Convert.ToDouble(s).ToString("000@000.00").Replace('.', ',').Replace('@', '.');
```

Comment: Is dividing by 1000 a necessary calculation? Surely creating a custom format would be easier and require less resources.

Comment: Creating a custom format is better; @Murphy11 did a good job there.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do it like this:

```
// save parsing, ignoring current settings
double d = double.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// whatever culture you actually want, assuming German
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de");
string formatted = d.ToString(culture);
```