# Formatting currency

Tags: c#

In the example below, comma is the decimal separator.

I have this : 125456,89

I'd like have this : 125.456,89; other exemple : 23456789,89  => 23.456.789,89

Thanks,

Comment: What culture is this, and what is the type of your input?

Comment: French culture, but the formatting must be NOT depending of the regional settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually to format a number as a currency, you should use the "c" format specifier:

```
string formatted = price.ToString("c");
```

That will use the current thread's default culture to determine the formatting rules, but you can specify it explicitly if you want.

If that doesn't help, please give us more information and read these two pages:

- [Standard numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)
- [Custom numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

EDIT: From your comment, it sounds like you *either* want to specify an explicit custom numeric format string, *or* build your own `NumberFormatInfo` object (which is just a matter of setting properties after cloning an existing one) and pass that into a formatting call.

Comment: Jon, is it possible to not have the € (in my case) before the number ?

Comment: @Kris-I: You could try changing the currency symbol to "" (for a custom NumericFormatInfo).

Answer (score 2):

look at this examples

```
double value = 12345.6789;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));

Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C3", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));

Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C3", 

              CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK")));

// The example displays the following output on a system whose
// current culture is English (United States):
//       $12,345.68
//       $12,345.679
//       kr 12.345,679
```

Comment: for more information about CurrencyDecimalSeparator and formats you can look at the NumberFormatInfo class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2xdwt6xx.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
125456.89.ToString("#,###.00")
```

It will automatically use the correct decimal point and group separator for the current culture. It differs from the other solutions so far in that it doesn't automatically append the currency symbol.

Comment: Almost good, when I have 12546,00 I'd like see 12.456,00 when I use it I have 12.456

Comment: @Kris-I: changed my answer, have a look

Answer (score 0):

quoted from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296806/double-tostring-for-formatting/5296939#5296939)

Create a custom NumberFormatInfo instance and pass that in when calling ToString().

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";

double s = 219171;
string result = s.ToString("N2", nfi);
```

NumberFormatInfo belongs to `System.Globalization`